# Comunicar dos aplicaciones moviles

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil

Buen día a la gente, espero se encuentren bien y con todo el animo este día lunes xd, soy desarrollador android y estoy a punto de cumplir un año, la situación es la siguiente: trabajo con dispositivos de x marca que funcionan como POS, el dispositivo trae impresora incorporada para boletas, facturas, etc. Tenemos un cliente que compro estos dispositivos y que esta desarrollando una aplicación en Expo y lamentablemente no hay librerías compatibles con Expo pero si hay con React Native, por lo que me explico el desarrollador Expo esas librerías no son compatible con Expo por x razón, por mi lado desarrollo aplicaciones para estos dispositivos bajo lenguaje JAVA con android studio ya que la documentación y librerías de todas las funcionalidades que tienen estos dispositivos están bajo lenguaje JAVA, entonces con el desarrollador Expo lanzamos varias ideas para poder solucionar este problema, una de ellas es que por mi lado cree un servicio en android studio que funcione en segundo plano el cual se comunique a través de Intent con la aplicación creada en Expo, es decir, la aplicación en Expo me enviaría una cadena base64 a través de Intent y yo realizo todo el proceso restante que es transformar a PDF y luego imprimir, pero con esta opción el desarrollador Expo no esta seguro como hacer los Intent en Expo (por mi lado investigue si se puede realizar Intent en Expo y encontré una librería que no estoy seguro si funcione en Expo, de todas formas se la envié y me dijo que probaría, también encontré que Expo tiene algo llamado Linking el cual también le mencione al desarrollador Expo pero no me dio una respuesta clara si funciona), por mi lado probé creando dos aplicaciones en android studio (con la intención de simular lo mas real posible esta solución) una tipo servicio y otra normal con un botón que envía el Intent al servicio con el String base64 pero estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

AppsFilter system_server I interacción: PackageSetting{49773d3 com.example.testintent/10201} -> PackageSetting{c917fcc com.example.testintentcencosud/10200} BLOQUEADO

ActivityManager system_server W No se puede iniciar el servicio Intent { cmp=com.example.testintentcencosud/.Servicio (tiene extras) } U=0: no encontrado

Agregar que en el manifest tengo estos dos permisos pensando que solucionaría este error:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_SERVICE" />
```

Agregar también que liste todos los paquetes del dispositivo y efectivamente me lista paquetes pero no me lista el paquete de la aplicación tipo servicio y tampoco me lista los paquetes de las aplicaciones creadas anteriormente, ignoro la razón y quizá ustedes me puedan ayudar o aclarar.

La otra opción es crear una base de datos SQLite que este en comunicación con las dos aplicaciones, el desarrollador Expo poblaría la base de datos y yo la consulto obteniendo los datos (la BD seria super simple, una tabla con 3 columnas: Int id, String base64, Boolean impreso), esta opción no se si es viable ya que desconozco si se puede tener una base de datos en común con otra aplicación creada en Expo. Espero me puedan ayudar ya sea aclarándome si son viable estas dos opciones explicadas anteriormente o cualquier otra opción que quizá no he considerado, una de las opciones descartadas es crear una API ya que los jefes no quieren que pase por internet esta comunicación entre las dos aplicaciones por razones de delay y bla bla, muchas gracias por su tiempo y su ayuda, estaré atento a sus respuestas, cualquier info que necesiten consulte.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La pregunta esta bien estructurada, pero mas alla del error que mostras, el resto parece una discusion sobre soluciones viables, y eso no va con el formato del sitio. Por favor centra tu pregunta en un problema especifico con una respuesta que no sea una discusion...